# Set the time to live (TTL) of IP packets for outgoing UDP datagrams on Arduino Ethernet

Tags: header, udp, ip, arduino, ttl

I'm using an Arduino Ethernet to send UDP datagrams to a remote host. The code I use to send a single datagram is:

```
Udp.begin(localPort);
...
Udp.beginPacket(remoteIP, remotePort);
Udp.write(data);
Udp.endPacket();
```

My issue is that I need to customize the TTL of the outgoing UDP/IP packet, but none of [Udp.begin](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPBegin), [Udp.beginPacket](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPBeginPacket), [Udp.write](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPWrite) and [Udp.endPacket](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPEndPacket) provide a parameter to set such option.

I know that the TTL field belongs to the [IP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header#Header) but it seems you don't handle raw IP packets using Arduino's Ethernet / socket / w5100 libraries.

I looked into the definitions of the above functions, expecially in `EthernetUDP::beginPacket` where I was wondering to find something useful being it called just before I pass the payload of the message, but I got stuck since it contains not much more than a call to `startUDP()` (socket.cpp), and the latter deals with methods of the W5100 class that are not clear to me.

Do someone know if there is a somehow high-level facility to set the TTL of a packet, or should one go deeper into the libraries to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. The WIZnet W5100 socket provide registers that describe the socket's behaviour as documented in [W5100 Datasheet Version 1.1.6](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/W5100_Datasheet_v1_1_6.pdf). One of these registers is `Socket 0 IP TTL (S0_TTL)` (address `0x0416`). I see that those registers are written in the `startUDP` function (in `socket.cpp`) in order to set the socket's destination IP address and port:

```
W5100.writeSnDIPR(s, addr);
W5100.writeSnDPORT(s, port);
```

so I appended there a call to

```
W5100.writeSnTTL(s, (uint8_t) 255); // set TTL to 255
```

and it indeed worked, i.e. the sketch got compiled. Such method is undocumented, I figured it out looking at the other register-writing methods and finding on the web that exists a couple of projects that make use of it.

I also wrote [this patch](http://pastebin.com/e8WtA5C8) to provide the override `Udp.beginPacket(remoteIP, remotePort, ttl)` to the Ethernet libraries that come with Arduino 1.0.1 - 2012.05.21.

Comment: just curious, do you remember what the TTL was by default? I'm having an issue with some network devices that receive packets just fine but I can't get a reply unless I'm on the same subnet, even with appropriate configurations on the intermediate switches

Comment: Default TTL in W5100 is 128.